# Question regarding grammar

Tags: grammatical-case

I read this sentence in an article -
" black people have claim upon everything as whites " .
Is this sentence grammatically correct and what does it imply

Comment: It is poorly constructed at best.  It's technically "correct grammar", I guess, but is ambiguous and not idiomatic.

Comment: Actually I was more curious about usage of as , Wouldn't it be better if it was " Black people have equal claim upon everything as whites have "

Comment: How about "Black people should have the same rights as whites.  But they don't."?

Comment: But it's more like they're not provided with equal rights .. but Constitution has provided them equal rights it's just people who don't let them enjoy their rights by means of humiliation or whatever else

Comment: The Constitution has stated that they *should* have equal rights, but that doesn't mean that they *actually* have equal rights.  (What is it that you are trying to say?)

Comment: it's probably going awkward letsbtake another example , If i said " I live under the same roof as you " would it be grammatically correct ?

Comment: That one is grammatically correct and reasonably idiomatic (even if untrue).

Comment: Would it be correct if i said - " I am on the same page as you "